# Incrementing value of an object when is called (JS)

Tags: javascript, json, mootools, increment

I have an object part of an class and I want to increment it's value everytime when is called.

```
var up = new FancyUpload2($('demo-status'), $('demo-list'), { // options object  
verbose: true  

    data: { 'file_number' : value },  
});
```

"data:" is part of [POST]; I would like to have incremental value on 'file_number' everytime when a POST call is executed (next time value = value + 1)

(the class FancyUpload2 uses Swiff.Uploader class and MooTools 122 and I found it on internet as freeware)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

to change the value you could use something like this externally (if the class implements Options, which i think it does):

```
up.setOptions({
    data: {
        file_number: up.options.data.file_number++
    }
});
```

you can attach to your `fileComplete` event:

eg, on instigate, add to options:

```
onFileComplete: function() {
    // bad practice to access the options object like so but it works.
    this.options.data.file_number++;
}
```

have fun.

Comment: ok, thank you.I have tried all possibilities, including your suggestion too but no luck. Can I PM you with an example ?

Comment: the author of fancyupload is an actual visitor here on SO, you are better off asking him to comment, although w/o seeing your actual code that you have tried etc, it won't be easy to narrow down. I will let him know there's a question for him next time i see him on IRC or you are welcome to come to #mootools on irc.freenode.net and ask about this or wait for @digitarald to arrive.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried a few times to contact him (his website form, email), but no answer, that's why I have asked here. Anyway, I will try also on IRC. Thnx once again !